# Aligned numbered equations in a table using eqnarray

Tags: tables, equations, align

I am writing a paper to Springer journal (class: svjour3), I put an algorithm in a table and I used **eqnarray** to ensure the alignment and numbering of the equations, but there is a problem with the long equations when I split them, because the split parts are all numbered, but what I want is just to number the last part. How can I do that using **eqnarray**?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,natbib]{svjour3}         
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- new
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,         % or letterpaper
  textwidth=15cm,  % llncs has 12.2cm
  textheight=24cm, % llncs has 19.3cm
  heightrounded,   % integer number of lines
  hratio=1:1,      % horizontally centered
  vratio=2:3,      % not vertically centered
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\DiffQR}{DiffQR}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%end Packages--------------------------------------------------

%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
%\hypersetup{draft}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Alg}\label{tab:Table1}

\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
\subsubsection*{\textbf{Initialization}}

\subsubsection*{\textbf{Time update}}
The partial derivatives of the time update equations are 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}{\partial \theta_j} &=& \frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}}{\partial \theta_j}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{S}_{k-1|k-1}}{\partial \theta_j} \bm{\xi}_i\\
\label{eq:Equat_1}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}_{i,k|k-1}^*}{\partial \theta_j} 
 &=& \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta})}{\partial \theta_j}\\
 &=& \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta_j})}{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}\frac{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}{\partial \theta_j} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta})}{\partial \theta_j}
\label{eq:Equat_2}
\end{eqnarray}
\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) stop using eqnarray, it is broken in too many ways, you're already loading amsmath so use the constructions in it. (2) why do you have textbf inside sections? (2) why do you have a table float around the whole thing? Probably better to use some of the packages that can describe algorithms, there are also packages that can make algorithms float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are specialized packages for algorithms instead of using a table for it. You have too many options to select from within what suits your needs,

- `algorithm` - float wrapper for algorithms.
- `algorithmic` - first algorithm typesetting environment.
- `algorithmicx` - second algorithm typesetting environment.
- `algpseudocode` - layout for `algorithmicx`.
- `algorithm2e` -  third algorithm typesetting environment.

I will leave the choice for you to decide after some reading. Finally, don't use `eqnarray`, it is deprecated, use `align` instead from `amsmath` with `\notag` for unnumbered equations.

```
\documentclass[smallextended,natbib]{svjour3}         
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- new
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,         % or letterpaper
  textwidth=15cm,  % llncs has 12.2cm
  textheight=24cm, % llncs has 19.3cm
  heightrounded,   % integer number of lines
  hratio=1:1,      % horizontally centered
  vratio=2:3,      % not vertically centered
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\DiffQR}{DiffQR}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%end Packages--------------------------------------------------

%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
%\hypersetup{draft}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Alg}\label{tab:Table1}
\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
\subsubsection*{Initialization}
\subsubsection*{Time update}
The partial derivatives of the time update equations are 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}{\partial \theta_j} &= \frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}}{\partial \theta_j}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{S}_{k-1|k-1}}{\partial \theta_j} \bm{\xi}_i\notag\\ %\label{eq:Equat_1}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}_{i,k|k-1}^*}{\partial \theta_j} 
 &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta})}{\partial \theta_j} \notag\\
 &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta_j})}{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}\frac{\partial {\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1}}}{\partial \theta_j} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{X}_{i,k-1|k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1},\bm{\theta})}{\partial \theta_j}
\label{eq:Equat_2}
\end{align}
\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answers solve my problem partially, but is there a way to number the first equation also.

Comment: Sure, just remove the first `\notag` to allow the equation number. Also uncomment `\label{eq:Equat_1}` to be able to refer to the equation.